# Minikube Ingress: unexpected error reading configmap kube-system/tcp-services: configmap kube-system/tcp-services was not found

Tags: minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I am running minikube with below configuration

**Environment**:

- minikube version: **v0.25.2**
- macOS version:    **10.12.6**
- DriverName:       **virtualbox**
- ISO:              **minikube-v0.25.1.iso**

I created **Ingress** resource to map service:`messy-chimp-emauser` to path: `/`

But when I am rolling-out changes to minikube, I am getting below logs in the pod for `nginx-ingress-controller`

```
   5 controller.go:811] service default/messy-chimp-emauser does not have any active endpoints
   5 controller.go:245] unexpected error reading configmap kube-system/tcp-services: configmap kube-system/tcp-services was not found
   5 controller.go:245] unexpected error reading configmap kube-system/udp-services: configmap kube-system/udp-services was not found
```

And hence getting HTTP - 503 when trying to access service from browser

**Steps to reproduce**

STEP 1
`minikube addons enable ingress`

STEP 2
`kubectl create -f kube-resources.yml` 
(replaced actual-image with `k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4`)

**kube-resources.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: messy-chimp-emauser
  labels:
    app: messy-chimp-emauser
    chart: emauser-0.1.0
    release: messy-chimp
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: emauser
  selector:
    app: messy-chimp-emauser
    release: messy-chimp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: messy-chimp-emauser
  labels:
    app: emauser
    chart: emauser-0.1.0
    release: messy-chimp
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: emauser
      release: messy-chimp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: emauser
        release: messy-chimp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: emauser
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: messy-chimp-ema-chart
  labels:
    app: ema-chart
    chart: ema-chart-0.1.0
    release: messy-chimp
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: messy-chimp-emauser
              servicePort: emauser
```

Request to please suggest on this.

Comment: The issue was because service-selector not matching pod-labels